# carrierwave multiple file uploads and storing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I want to do a multiple file upload with carrierwave.

When I upload I transcode a movie in sveral formats .mp4 .mov ...

Now I want to upload all those and store them in DB?

how can I save versions of a file with carrierwave?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the relevant attributes to your model and introduce a before_save callback.

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :video, VideoUploader

  before_save :update_video_attributes
  private

  def update_video_attributes
    if video.present? && video_changed?
      self.content_type = video.file.content_type
      self.file_size = video.file.size
    end
  end
end
```

For more details see [github](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Store-the-uploaded-file-size-and-content-type)

Comment: Can I do this in carrierwave uploader too? do I have to set for each element a special column in table?